# count distinct and calculate percent differences in two columns ifrom R dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

have a simple dataframe listing types of products and tag number per a couple of months:

```
data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                month = c("jan","jan","jan","jan",
                       "jan","feb","feb","feb","feb"),
                category = c("TB", "GT", "TB", "YT", "GT", "TB", "GT", "TB", "YT"),
                tag_number = c(101L, 101L, 223L, 223L, 223L, 345L, 345L, 655L, 223L)
)

month category tag_number

jan      TB     101
jan      GT     101
jan      TB     223
jan      YT     223
jan      GT     223
feb      TB     345
feb      GT     345
feb      TB     655
feb      YT     223
```

I want to compare  and extract the percentual difference between the unique tag_number values by month and category.

Let me explain a bit more as this seems a complicated issue.

If we get grouped month and categories we get to compare this table (month+category)

```
Jan  TB  101, 223    vs.    Feb  TB  345, 655
Jan  GT  101, 223    vs.    Feb  GT  345
Jan  YT  223         vs.    Feb  YT  223
```

In January the TB category has two unique tag numbers (101 and 223). If you compare with February there are two unique tags too, but none of them are equal so the percent difference between months is 100% and the count distinct is two in both cases.

Same for GT category. All tags are different. So again 100%.

Different case is YT. Both months contained the same tag number so the difference is 0%

Here expected result. The percent diff is the percentage of cases distinct between months.

Let's take TB category.

4 unique values total, 2 unique per month, none of them equal so:

4 / 4 = 1  (so 100%)

```
category   pct_diff
TB           100%
GT           100%
YT             0%
```

Comment: How do you get the `count_distinct_diff` value? What does it stand for? Also the `pct_diff`. How is that calculated?

Comment: compare tag numbers in TB (101, 223) and TG (345, 655) . All are different between jan and feb, so there is two distinct tags per month and none of them coincident between months, so the 100%

Comment: I don't understand how you calculated count_distinct_di and pct_diff

Comment: You have two months ion your example, but only one pct_diff column. So is ct_diff referring to jan or feb? As you can so, all of us have problems understanding your rationale. So it would be good if you'd update your post with a calculation example. unique tags jan/feb are clear. The other two vars are not.

Comment: So in your explained example, what would be your expected value if e.g. one Feb/TB value was 223 for the pct diff? Is it still 100% because in both Jan and Feb there are no identical values? Or is it 50% because 50% (2 out of 4) values for Jan/Feb are identical?

Comment: 50%. We expect the percent of cases that are different. So if half of tag numbers are different between months  this is 50%. If one third part is different then 33%, and so on…

Comment: So you just look at all calues for Jan and Feb combined (for TB) and count how many are unique, is that correct?

Comment: And extract the differences between Jan and feb to calculate percent per category and month, yes

Comment: Sorry, I still don‘t get it. At least for the count_distinct_diff column. How is it 2 for TB and 3 for GT?  And why is pct_ diff now per category AND month if just just confirmed that the percent should be across Jan/Feb?

Comment: count-distinct-diff column is not necessary. I just included it to clarify but is leading to confusion (my bad).  You should compare month+category. So jan+TB compared to jan+TB

Comment: Ok, so one more question on a few examples. Let‘s assume the following cases. Please tell what would be your expected output: 1. TB/ jan: 123, 234, feb: 234; 2. tb/jan: 123, 234, feb = 123, 987; 3. tb/jan = 123,234,345, feb = 234, 456.

Comment: Why do not you, @Forge, provide a mathematical formula to calculate the wanted percentage? That would be most useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df %>%
   group_by(category) %>%
   summarise(perc_diff = 100 * mean(table(tag_number) == 1))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  category perc_diff
  <chr>        <dbl>
1 GT             100
2 TB             100
3 YT               0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution, but I am not sure whether it can be generalized to a larger case.
The approach is to create a wide table then calculate difference percentage.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  month = c("jan","jan","jan","jan",
            "jan","feb","feb","feb","feb"),
  category = c("TB", "GT", "TB", "YT", "GT", "TB", "GT", "TB", "YT"),
  tag_number = c(101L, 101L, 223L, 223L, 223L, 345L, 345L, 655L, 223L)
 )

df2 <- df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "month", values_from = "tag_number") %>% 
  mutate(both_months = map2(jan, feb, ~intersect(.x,.y))) %>%  #find intersect
  mutate(all_lenght = map2(jan,feb, ~union(.x,.y))) %>%  #find all length
  mutate(percent_diff = map2(both_months, all_lenght, 
                             ~(100 - length(.x)*100/length(.y))) %>% 
                        unlist()) # calculate difference percentage

df2

#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>   category jan       feb       both_months all_lenght percent_diff
#>   <chr>    <list>    <list>    <list>      <list>            <dbl>
#> 1 TB       <int [2]> <int [2]> <int [0]>   <int [4]>           100
#> 2 GT       <int [2]> <int [1]> <int [0]>   <int [3]>           100
#> 3 YT       <int [1]> <int [1]> <int [1]>   <int [1]>             0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the base R code below

```
transform(
  reshape(
    aggregate(
      tag_number ~ .,
      df,
      toString
    ),
    direction = "wide",
    idvar = "category",
    timevar = "month"
  ),
  pct_diff = mapply(
    function(...) {
      sprintf("%s%%", mean(table(unlist(c(...))) == 1) * 100)
    },
    strsplit(tag_number.feb, ", "),
    strsplit(tag_number.jan, ", ")
  )
)
```

which gives

```
  category tag_number.feb tag_number.jan pct_diff
1       GT            345       101, 223     100%
3       TB       345, 655       101, 223     100%
5       YT            223            223       0%
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to come up with a solution that will show you the percentage of unie values based on month-pairs that scales to more than two months.

The code can be shortened by combining rows, but I kept it like this so you can easily inspect the results of each step, to help you understand what is actually happening.

```
library(data.table)
# make mydata a data.table
setDT(mydata)
mydata[, month_f := factor(month, labels = c("jan", "feb"))]
#build list columns 'tags', containing a list of all tag-values for that month + category
tags <- mydata[, .(alltags = as.list(.SD)), by = .(month_f, category)]
# build lookup table with all month >> month combinations
ans <- CJ(month  = unique(mydata$month_f), 
   month2 = unique(mydata$month_f),
   category = unique(mydata$category))
# join in the tags for month and month2
ans[tags, tags  := i.alltags, on = .(month = month_f, category)]
ans[tags, tags2 := i.alltags, on = .(month2 = month_f, category)]
# find overlapping values between tags and tags2 list columns
ans[, tags_overlap := Map(intersect, tags, tags2)][]
# calculate the percentage of the overlap
myfun <- function(x, y) {
  paste0(100 * (1 - (length(x) / length(y))), "%")
}
ans[, unique := Map(myfun, tags_overlap, tags)][]
# cast to wide format
dcast(ans, category + month ~ month2, value.var = "unique")
#    category month  jan  feb
# 1:       GT   jan   0% 100%
# 2:       GT   feb 100%   0%
# 3:       TB   jan   0% 100%
# 4:       TB   feb 100%   0%
# 5:       YT   jan   0%   0%
# 6:       YT   feb   0%   0%
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution, based on `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  month = c("jan","jan","jan","jan",
            "jan","feb","feb","feb","feb"),
  category = c("TB", "GT", "TB", "YT", "GT", "TB", "GT", "TB", "YT"),
  tag_number = c(101L, 101L, 223L, 223L, 223L, 345L, 345L, 655L, 223L)
)

df %>% 
  group_by(category) %>% 
  summarise(
    pct_diff = 100 * (1 - 2*length(
    intersect(tag_number[month == "jan"], tag_number[month == "feb"]))
    / length(tag_number)), .groups = "drop")

#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   category pct_diff
#>   <chr>       <dbl>
#> 1 GT            100
#> 2 TB            100
#> 3 YT              0
```

Answer (score 0):

Super interesting puzzle.  First thing I did was to expand the test data a little and use actual dates rather than character strings so I could utilize the natural ordering.  I added a few more test cases just for laughs.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  month = c(as.Date("2019-01-01"),as.Date("2019-01-01"),as.Date("2019-01-01"),as.Date("2019-01-01"),
            as.Date("2019-01-01"),as.Date("2019-01-01"),as.Date("2019-01-01"),as.Date("2019-02-01"),
            as.Date("2019-02-01"),as.Date("2019-02-01"),as.Date("2019-02-01"),as.Date("2019-02-01"),
            as.Date("2019-02-01"),as.Date("2019-03-01"),as.Date("2019-03-01"),as.Date("2019-03-01"),
            as.Date("2019-03-01"),as.Date("2019-04-01"),as.Date("2019-04-01"),as.Date("2019-04-01"),
            as.Date("2019-04-01"),as.Date("2019-04-01")),
  category = c("TB", "GT", "TB", "YT", "GT", "TB", "GT", "ZW", "YT", "TB", "GT", "TB", "YT", "GT", 
               "TB", "GT", "TB", "YT", "TB", "YT", "TB", "GT"),
  tag_number = c(101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 655L, 345L, 345L, 345L, 345L, 
                 223L, 655L, 345L, 223L, 345L, 655L, 101L, 379L, 345L))
```

Then I considered your question from the set theory perspective.  The question you are asking is essentially "What is the percentage new tags occurring this month (setdiff) of the total tags over this and the preceding month (union)?" Here is a little function to answer that question along with minimal error handling for the first month.

```
g <- function(t)
  {
    r <- c()
    for (i in seq_along(t))
      {
        if (i == 1 & length(t[[i]] > 0))             { r <- c(1) } 
          else if (i == 1 & length(t[[i]]) == 0)     { r <- c(0) }
          else { r <- c(r, length(Reduce(setdiff, list(t[[i]], t[[i-1]]))) 
                              / length(union(t[[i-1]], t[[i]]))) }
      }
    return(r)
  }
```

Then, I used pivot_wider to put the data into a form with the date as a unique identifier and each category in a column, and finally applied the function to each of the columns.  Et voilà.

```
s <- df %>% group_by(month) %>%
            unique() %>%
            pivot_wider(id_cols = month, 
                     names_from = category, 
                    values_from = tag_number, 
                      values_fn = list) %>%
            map_if(is.list, ~ g(.x))

List of 5
 $ month: Date[1:4], format: "2019-01-01" "2019-02-01" ...
 $ TB   : num [1:4] 1 0.5 0.667 0.333
 $ GT   : num [1:4] 1 0.5 0.5 0
 $ YT   : num [1:4] 1 0.667 0 1
 $ ZW   : num [1:4] 0 1 0 NaN
```